# A change of wording is needed (Solved)

Tags: phrases, synonyms, legalese

In a legal document I am having to edit certain specific phrases, though I have managed to do most I am stuck on a way to change the wording of the phrase        "[Company Name] hereby appoints" and still making sound official as it is a legal document. It is a part of a statement that allows a reseller to sell our products.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Again the phrase I need to change is "[Company Name] hereby appoints"

Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what's wrong with "hereby appoints", or we're just guessing.

Comment: And why do you have to change it? Does it still have to pass as a legal document after you revise it?

Comment: Sorry the problem is that I don't actually know the problem with it. My boss walked in placed the document on my desk and said "I've circled anything that needs changing or removing, thanks" then left.

Comment: @Mai_W do you think your boss may be unhappy with 'appoint', because it suggests employing someone for a particular role within your company? I am not sure of the correct legal terminology, but perhaps 'permitting' or 'contracting' or 'outsourcing' may be more appropriate?

Comment: Documents don't have to be stuffy or convoluted to be legal. *Designates* or *authorizes* might be appropriate, but there is nothing wrong with *appoints* unless it means something special in your business or locale.

Comment: Why are you editing a legal document if you don't know the appropriate legal terms to use?  Legalese can be *very* specific and I'm not sure that you will get proper suggestions on a general-English site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about 'Company X hereby sanctions/mandates the resale of its products by company Y'?

Comment: Thank you. My bosses feedback on this was "It sound better now, thank you"

Answer (score 0):

What about [Company Name] hereby nominates

or [Company Name] hereby choose

Comment: Nominate and Appoint have different meanings.

Comment: but in this context they have the same meaning which is  [Company Name] hereby propose or choose or decide, they all have the same meaning in here.

Comment: A contract lawyer would disagree with you.

Comment: the purpose of the statement is that it allows a reseller to sell products. so iam still convinced that the word choose is the best for this context. @chenmunka maybe yes maybe not